# A function whose declared type is neither 'undefined', 'void', nor 'any' must return a value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How can I return a boolean that indicates if locatization has been possible or not?

```
locate() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      let isLocationAvailable = false;
      Geolocation.checkPermissions().then((currentPermissions) => {
        console.log("[Geolocation] checkPermissions currentPermissions permissions.location:", currentPermissions.location, ", permissions.coarseLocation:", currentPermissions.coarseLocation);
        if ((currentPermissions.location === 'granted') || (currentPermissions.coarseLocation === 'granted')) {
          isLocationAvailable = true;
        }
        else
          if ((currentPermissions.location === 'prompt') || (currentPermissions.location === 'prompt-with-rationale')
            || (currentPermissions.coarseLocation === 'prompt') || (currentPermissions.coarseLocation === 'prompt-with-rationale')) {
            console.log("[Geolocation] requestPermissions");
            Geolocation.requestPermissions().then((permissions) => {
              console.log("[Geolocation] requestPermissions permissions.location:", permissions.location, ", permissions.coarseLocation:", permissions.coarseLocation);
              if ((permissions.location === 'granted') || (permissions.coarseLocation === 'granted')) {
                isLocationAvailable = true;
              }
              else {
                isLocationAvailable = false;
              }
            });
          }
          else {
            isLocationAvailable = false;
          }
      }).finally(() => {

        if (isLocationAvailable)
          Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000 }).then((position) => {
            let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            this.map.setCenter(latLng);

            if (this.myPositionMarker == null) {
              this.translate.get("Usted está aquí").subscribe((str: string) => {
                this.myPositionMarker = this.addMarker(latLng, 'assets/img/marker-youarehere.png', str);
              });
            }
            else {
              this.myPositionMarker.setPosition(latLng);
            }
          }).catch(error => {
            this.translate.get(["Localización", "Compruebe que está activada la ubicación de su dispositivo", "OK"]).subscribe((strs: string[]) => {
              this.common.showMessage(strs["Localización"], '', strs["Compruebe que está activada la ubicación de su dispositivo"]);
            });
          });
         else {
          //this.common.showMessage("","","Conceda permisos de geolocalización a la aplicación para poder geolocalizar su posición.");
        } 
      });
    });
  }
```

I have tried to set a boolean return value but i get the error " A function whose declared type is neither 'undefined', 'void', nor 'any' must return a value."

Comment: I can't see the return keyword in your code and I can see no declared type. Are you on AngularJS or Angular 2 (Typescript)?

Comment: Angular 2 (Typescript)
I have not written the returns because I do not know how to write then to avoid the error. If I return true after the promises I get the error I set in the title.
I want to be able to return isLocationAvailable after I know if geolocation is available or not.

Comment: I would advise to write the code which gives the error in order to correct it

Answer (score 0):

return boolean value from function and declare function name as below:

```
locate(): boolean {
    // your logic
}
```